# Changing Table View grouped style text color globally

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, tableview

I want to change text colour in section grouped header **Globally**. I tried

```
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView.appearance().textLabel?.textColor = barColor
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView.appearance().textLabel?.backgroundColor = barColor
```

but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105747/how-to-change-font-color-of-the-title-in-grouped-type-uitableview

Answer (score 3):

```
UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UITableViewHeaderFooterView.self]).textColor = barColor
```

fixed that for me.

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30845710/6310412